# Cycle through multiple dates

Tags: php, api, date, loops

I'm currently working on a little calendar using the API of a databank filled with events. (I have no control of the contents of the database). But the events in the database contain different formats of dates. (some are just dd-mm-yy, some are like 'wednesday 12/06/13', some are multiple dates together '12/06/13, 13/06/13, 14/06/13',... and so on.)

So the only problem I have are the multiple dates together because I need the first date after today.

Example: Database contains: 12/06/13, 13/06/13, 14/06/13, 15/06/13, 17/06/13 -> I need the 17/06/13.

With the current code I remove alle different symbols so I only have the numbers remaining, and convert the first 6 numbers to a date:

```
foreach($events as $e)
{
    $start = 0;
    $length = 6;
    $rawDate = $e->calendarsummary;
    $filterDate = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $rawDate);
    $oneDate = substr($filterDate, $start, $length);
    $finalDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('dmy', $oneDate);
    echo $finalDate->format('l j/m/y');
}
```

So this gives me the first date in the series, but I need the first one after today. Is there anyone with a suggestion?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using the DateTime class you can do a direct comparison, something like this:-

```
$dateString = "12/06/13, 13/06/13, 14/06/13, 15/06/13, 17/06/13, 20/06/13";

$dates = explode(', ', $dateString);
$now = new DateTime();
foreach($dates as $date){
    $dateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/y', $date);
    if($dateTime > $now){
        $result = $dateTime;
        break;
    }
}

echo $result->format('d/m/y');
```

Output:-

> 17/06/13

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to check `$rawDate` for a comma using PHP's `strpos()` function. If no comma exists, continue as normal.

However, if a comma is found, you'll need to use the PHP `explode()` function to break the date string into an array of dates. If they are not in date order already, you'll need to sort the array according using PHP's `usort()` function. Once you have them in order, you can loop through them and choose the first one whose date is greater than today. Once you have that date, you can then proceed as normal.

Obviously, there may be 50 different ways to do this,

I'd be happy to help you hash out the code if you keep me posted as to what you've tried.

```
foreach($events as $e){
    $start = 0;
    $length = 6;
    $rawDate = $e->calendarsummary;

    if (strpos($rawDate, ',')!==false){ //Comma Found, do Explode
        $dates = explode(',', $rawDate);
        usort($dates, 'sortDates');


        foreach($dates as $d){
            $tempDate = new DateTime($d);
            //Do date calculations here to see if the date is beyond today's date.

            //if it is, set $rawDate = $d and continue
            if (...){
                $rawDate=$d;
                break;
            }
        }
    }


    $filterDate = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $rawDate);
    $oneDate = substr($filterDate, $start, $length);
    $finalDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('dmy', $oneDate);
    echo $finalDate->format('l j/m/y');
}

function sortDates($aItem, $bItem){
    $temp = new DateTime($aItem);
    $a = $temp->getTimestamp();

    $temp = new DateTime($bItem);
    $b = $temp->getTimestamp();

    if ($a == $b) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;
}
```

**More Info:**

- [strpos()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)
- [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)
- [usort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)